# Proving the number of solutions for a equation

Tags: real-analysis

**Prove that the equation 
$$\ x^{180} +\frac{84}{1+x^2+\cos^2 x} = 119$$
has at least two solutions.**

At most the number of solutions can go up to is $182$ since it is the greatest power available on the variable. However in regards to at least two, I think the $x^2$ term in the denominator has something to do with it, however, I cannot properly work out a reason.

There's atleast 1 solution since the sign changes of the equation $y= x^{180} +\frac{84}{1+x^2+\cos^2 x} - 119$ at the interval $[~0,\infty)$.

It would be very helpful if someone could provide some hints.

Comment: This is not a polynomial equation, hence the exponent of $x$ does not necessarily determine the number of solutions. You need two things: continuity and the fact that the function involved is an even function. So if one solution exists in $(0,\infty)$, then another must exist in $(-\infty, 0)$.

Comment: By continuity, there's 1 solution, and by even function, there is the second solution (the negative of the solution found by the continuity). Right? Btw the reason we know the function is even is because all powers are even right?

Comment: Yes for the first part and no for the second part. The evenness of the function is not just based on powers of $x$. For example $\cos x$ is an even function and so is $x \sin x$. All we need is to ensure that $f(x)=f(-x)$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At $x=1$, $$\ x^{180} +\frac{84}{1+x^2+\cos^2 x} < 43 < 119$$

Since the denominator in $\frac{84}{1+x^2+\cos^2 x}$ is always more than $1$ (and never negative or zero),
for $x=2$ 
 $$\ x^{180} +\frac{84}{1+x^2+\cos^2 x} > 2^{180} > 119$$
Similarly, for $x= 2$
$$\ x^{180} +\frac{84}{1+x^2+\cos^2 x} > (-2)2^{180}=4^{90} > 119$$

Finally, since 
$$f(x) = \ x^{180} +\frac{84}{1+x^2+\cos^2 x} $$ can be generated from continuous functions of $x$ using only positive exponentiation, division by an inherently positive quantity, and addition and multiplication, $f(x)$ is itself continuous.  The intermediate value theorem then tells you it must attain the value $119$ in the interval $(-2,1)$ and again in the interval $(1,2)$.  Those points are two real solutions.

Comment: You lost a minus sign for the third case $x=-2$ and have an extra $2$ a little later.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f(x)=x^{180}+\dfrac{84}{x^2+\cos ^2(x)+1}-119$.

It is even, $f(0)=-77$ is negative and $f(2)\approx 2^{180}$ is positive therefore $f(x)$ has a zero in $(0,2)$ and another one in $(-2,0)$

$x\approx \pm 1.0248386$